# Open Graph protocol not working for my php website

Tags: php, whatsapp

I am trying to add a thumb nail image with some details about my website when sharing it via Whatsapp.
My share link button is placed at http://MY_IP/sms/index.php as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>My Whatsapp Test</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon_2.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Tests</h1>

        <div style="margin-top: 50px;">
            <a href="whatsapp://send?phone=+918129664901&text=<?php echo urlencode('http://MY_IP/sms/test.php'); ?>" data-action="share/whatsapp/share" style="background-color: green;color: #fff;font-size: 30px;font-weight: bold;width:150px;padding: 5px;" >Whatsapp 2</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And My website which I need to show in thumbnail is  http://MY_IP/sms/test.php as follows

```
<html>
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="How to change the address bar color in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari" />
<meta property="og:description" content="How to change the address bar color in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://MY_IP/sms/test.php" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://MY_IP/sms/logo.png" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hi</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I just browse http://MY_IP/sms/index.php in my mobile phone and clicked the **Whatsapp 2** button. It opens my Whatsapp as follows

[image]

Every thing ok except the "Thumb Nail". **logo.png** size is 31.9KB and dimension is 256 X 256. Please help me

Comment: You probably need to use https in order to show up in whatsapp

Comment: Thanks very much. Today I upgraded my website to https and now it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changed http to https. Now it is working fine. (Followed the comment from [Sky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2570054/sky))